# OperationQueue.cancelAllOperations does not call deinit method

Tags: ios, iphone, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

In a `for` loop, I'm adding 10 operations in a queue. Also I'm setting `maxConcurrentOperationCount = 3`. In `viewWillDisappear` I'm calling `cancelAllOperations`. When, for ex. 3 operations are executed, they are removed from the queue, regarding setting the `isFinished` to true, but only the next 3 operations are cancelled, which is expected. After going back to the previous screen, `deinit` in this case is not called. If I cancelled them after 7-8 were executed, `deinit` would be called. Why is this happening? What about the rest of them that are not even started? If I comment `maxConcurrentOperationCount = 3`, `deinit` is called.

Comment: deinit on which object? Your view controller or the operations?

Comment: Deinit of the ViewController.